# How can I figure out why my Thymeleaf pages are rendered so slowly?

Tags: spring-boot, performance, thymeleaf

The current project I am working on is using Spring boot 2.3.1.RELEASE and therfore Thymeleaf 3. We heavily use fragments th:includes and th:replaces and our webpages render terribly slow in local development.

Deployed almost every page loads instantly, but in local development some pages take up to 20, 25 seconds to render. While debugging I can see that we spend some time on DB access (~ 5 seconds) which still leaves about 20 seconds for the rendering.

I can see the elements of one page popping up one by one with a difference of seconds between them.

My question is now - how can I properly profile this to figure out why the thymeleaf rendering seems to be so slow in local development?

Update - spent some time playing around with VisualVM and now I figured out this:

[image]

Which at least proofs that the time is really spent by rendering Thymeleaf objects.

I will now try to debug why the AbstractElementProcessor takes so much time. Any tips for improving our template performance are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to VisualVM I got to the root of the problem:

[image]

It turns out most of the rendering time was spent on refreshing the message properties because the caching was set up wrongly, or rather disabled on purpose. (We used a `source.setCacheSeconds(0)` on our `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource`. After changing that caching to a reasonable value the rendering was fast.